# Display Dynamically the evolution of While

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, animation

Assume that in the place of `RandomInteger` what obtains is the result of a simulation step (the $j-th$ step).

```
j = 0;
While[
  j < 10,
  RandomInteger[{0, 100},5];
  j++
 ]
```

Also, assume that the maximum number of iterations (10 in the example above) is a parameter of the simulation. Consider that the same thing applies for the length of the output list (ie 5).

```
main[J_, x_] := Module[{j},
  j = 0;
  While[
   j < J,
   RandomInteger[{0, 100}, x];
   j++
  ]
 ]
```

(I understand that `main` is not supposed to output anything, like this. In order to get an output, you can enclose `RandomInteger` in `Sow` and apply `Reap` on `While`. But that is not what I'm trying to do.)

Using a variation of the `main` function defined above in a `Dynamic` context produces nothing:

```
DynamicModule[{J, x, j},
  Row@{
   Column@{
     Row@{"J", Null, Slider[Dynamic[J], {9, 13, 1}], Null, Dynamic[J]},
     Row@{"x", Null, Slider[Dynamic[x], {2, 7, 1}], Null, Dynamic[x]},
    },
   Null,
   Framed@main[Dynamic[J], Dynamic[x]]
  }
 ]
```

This is the '*dynamic*' `main`:

```
main[J_, x_] := DynamicModule[{j},
    j = 0;
    While[
      j < Dynamic[J],
      ListPlot[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, Dynamic[x]]];
      j++
    ]
 ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**update**

I have had success with a stripped down version of `main`:

```
main[Dynamic[J_], Dynamic[x_]] := DynamicModule[{},

  ListPlot[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, x], Frame -> True]

 ]
```

(also, I had to insert another `Dynamic` between `Framed` and `main`:
`Framed@Dynamic@main[Dynamic[J], Dynamic[x]]` in the calling code (see above))

The downside is that with this version, I can only visualize lists of varying `Length` (`Dynamic[x]`). I still have not figured out a way to visualize what goes on inside the loop (how to display a succession of `Listplot`'s).

---

**update2:**

I wanted to replicate [this](http://ncase.me/trust/) (display tournaments dynamically, mostly). I have so far gotten to [this](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/YYnh1aB2) (package) and [this](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/cjQR18HM) (`Manipulate`):

[image]

---

**update3:**

[This](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/1MuZGD2f) is the package with the additional functionality for repeated tournaments (evolutionary-ish) and [this](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/ayKyVFXJ) is the `Manipulate` code:

[image]

any suggestions for improvements esp. on the `Dynamic` side of things is particularly welcome.

Comment: `Dynamic[J]` is not a number, see: [5817](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/5478) and linked topics.

Comment: As the QA linked by Kuba explains, `Dynamic` is purely for *display*.  It has no room in any function which *computes* things (as opposed to display things computed elsewhere).

Comment: @Szabolcs: I've read the link (and the links in the link) @Kuba kindly provided. Let me see if I get this right: The only way to make an interactive display using the `Dynamic` functionality of some plots is to **first** generate them and then display them?

Comment: Yes, something like that.  You can't *compute* with `Dynamic[x]`.  `Dynamic[x]` is meant to be displayed, and it auto-updates whenever `x` changes.  If you want to display a plot, use `Dynamic@Plot[...]`.

Comment: related: [(71909)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71909/142)

Comment: Your question has been answered, and there are [things to do after that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Isn't any of the answers worth [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) ?

Comment: hello @rhermans, thanks for the reminder; I have not accepted any answer yet, because I have not conclusively determined which one of the methods described therein is more suitable for my problem (displaying dynamically the scores of the iterative prisoner's dilemma games). When i have a definitive result in my hands, I will chose an answer. (at this point I'm leaning towards "@Mathe172"'s approach because it seems straightforward)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html):

```
main[j_, J_, x_] := (j = 0; 
  While[j < J, Pause[0.5]; RandomInteger[{0, 100}, x]; j++])
SetAttributes[main, HoldFirst]

Monitor[main[j, 10, 10], StringForm["Current value of j: ``", j]]
```

I added a `Pause` so that you actually see the progress of this small example. The [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) attribute is added so that the function works if the variable already has a value assigned (we need to pass a reference instead of a value)

Comment: `Monitor` seems really powerful; the part in the documentation that states "... Any expression, including **graphics** and controls, can be given for *mon* " (my emphasis) seems promising. I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

If the only goal is to have some sort of Dynamic window into a long process (including tracking what plots are being generated and when) sometimes I'll make dynamic some argument to whatever holder function I've created to bundle data around.

i.e. say I've got some procedure that makes plots, cares about timestamp for some reason, and stores this stuff in some holder that gets passed around

```
ClearAll[f]; 
f[x_, holder_] := 
 Module[{time = Last@(Date[] - holder["datestamp"])}, 
  holder["currentPlot"] = Plot[y^x, {y, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> {y^x, time}];
   holder["allPlots"] = Append[holder["allPlots"] /. holder[___] :> {},
    {holder["plot"] , time}];
 ];
```

Then somewhere in a notebook for monitoring I'll execute something like:

```
Dynamic[holder["currentPlot"]]
```

Later if I execute:

```
x = -3; ClearAll[holder]; holder["datestamp"] = Date[];
While[ x <= 3,
 f[x, holder]; holder["datestamp"] = Date[];
 x += .1]
```

The `Output` cell of my earlier Dynamic[holder["plot"]] execution will now start displaying the various plots as they occur:

[image]