# How to suppress printing statments in function call

Tags: output, printing

I defined a function in Mathematica using `Module` similar to

```
function[a0_,b0_]:=Module[{a, b},
  a=a0;
  b=b0;
  subFunction[a,b];
  ...
]
```

Both `function` and `subFunction` (and possible `subSubFunctions`) contain `Print[]` statements.

My question: How can I call `function[]` and at the same time suppress all `Print[]` statements. I don't want to get the output of these `Print[]` statements. This should be done without changing the definitions of the functions.

Comment: `Function` is a builtin symbol. You can't name your own function `Function`. Generally, try not to start your own functions with capital letters to avoid such conflicts.  (I know that it was just an example.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and editing of my post!

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698754/message-generation-in-mathematica In addition to the answer given below, try using the `On, Off, Message` idiom. I think some built-in functions have `symbol::verbose` defined that you can turn `On` in order to see some internal progress messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
Block[{Print},
  function[]
]
```

A better solution is not to use `Print`.  A common debugging technique is to use a `myPrint` function instead of `Print` for printing debugging messages.  If this function is not defined, it's as if it weren't there. Nothing will be printed.  If you want to turn on debugging, then just `myPrint = Print`.  If you want to turn on debugging only temporarily, then `Block[{myPrint = Print}, function[]]`.

[Don't forget that Mathematica has a built-in debugger.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119962/12)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for. The `Print` statements I used were not meant for debugging but rather for expressing what `function` is doing. However I am not interested in these details when calling `function` several times just for getting the desired output.

Comment: @goe, as a suggestion for future development: you might want to implement your future functions to have an option (or optional argument) that would allow you to switch between simple and verbose modes, so that you won't have to resort to trickery like this.