# Breakpoints don't work in Wolfram Workbench

Tags: workbench

I have created `.m` file and `.nb` file outside Workbench. Both files are inside single directory. In the beginning of `.nb` file I put

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Import["my_file.m"]
```

as it is intended to work standalone.

Unfortunately, when I run any function in notebook, while breakpoints are set inside Workbench editor, neither is triggered.

How to make breakpoints work?

Comment: I never tried the Workbench debugger, but I thought you may find it useful to know that the builtin debugger works best if you use explicit commands to break instead of breakpoints (set using a GUI). https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119962/12