# How can I extract the raw data points with which NDSolve uses internally to make the InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a set of ODEs solved with NDSolve which returns InterpolatingFunctions. When I am trying to plot them, it takes a long time to render. I am guessing that adaptive subdivision for the sharp features makes it slow. My question is: since the interpolation was done internally before NDSolve returns, is there any way we can obtain the list of data points NDSolve used to interpolate? Thanks.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184132/debugging-ndsolve-to-see-numerical-values-at-each-time-step/184251#184251, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151845/taking-part-of-an-interpolatingfunction/152861#152861

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve

Answer (score 6):

```
iF = y /. NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}][[1]]
```

[image]

You can access the list of Properties of  `InterpolatingFunction` object using

```
 PropertyList[iF]
```

> ```
>  {"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh", "Evaluate", 
>    "GetPolynomial", "Grid", "InterpolationMethod", "InterpolationOrder", 
>    "MethodInformation", "Methods", "OutputDimensions", "Periodicity", "PlottableQ", 
>    "Properties", "QuantityUnits", "Unpack", "ValuesOnGrid"}
> ```

or

```
  iF["Methods"]
```

> same list

You can access the property `p` using `iF[p]`. For example,

```
iF["InterpolationOrder"]
```

> ```
>  {3}
> ```

```
iF["Coordinates"] // Short[#, 3] &
```

> [image]

```
iF["Grid"] // Short[#, 3] &
```

> [image]

```
iF["ValuesOnGrid"] // Short[#, 3] &
```

> [image]

etc.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: From @MichaelE2's [last link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve), you can also `ListPlot[iF]`.